# How to set time with DateTime modify?

Tags: php

Ok, we have `2018-04-09T10:00:00`

How to set time in:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $periodauction)->modify('-1 day, +4 hour')->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s')
```

It will return `2018-04-08T14:00:00`, so it works fine.

But how to set specific time like `18` unstead `+4 hour`. To get `2018-04-08T18:00:00` ?

Comment: Why not just set `$periodauction` to *equal* the desired time, and then skip the modification entirely?

Comment: Because `$periodauction` taken from the existing time from database to adjust the time for another table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the method [`setTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.settime.php) to specify an hour and minutes:

```
$periodauction = '2018-04-09T10:00:00';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $periodauction)->modify('-1 day');
$date->setTime(18,0);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
```

Outputs:

```
2018-04-08T18:00:00
```

Comment: Oh `setTime` ok

Answer (score 1):

Set time.

```php
$periodauction = '2018-04-09T10:00:00';

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $periodauction)->modify('-1 day t 18:00:00');

echo $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
```

Or

```php
$dateTime->modify('t 23:20:45');
```